# Empty admin view in custom objects after adding records using REST with "ääöö" characters

Tags: quickblox

Just learned that Scandinavian characters 'öäå' prevents Admin view to show ANY content of that class.

- Clean table
- Created a record from Admin panel with 'ööää', works just fine
- Added a record from my app with 'ooaa', works just fine

Image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/106346333@N02/10435376765/

Return JSON:

{"CLOSED_BY_USER":false,"FRIENDLY_NAME":"ooaa: Code","LAST_ACTIVITY":1382510280,"PRO_TEAM":null,"SHARED_SECRET":"salaisuus","SHARING_PROFILE":2,"STARTED":1382510281,"_id":"52676ed8535c12d655000b39","_parent_id":null,"created_at":1382510296,"updated_at":1382510296,"user_id":604824,"permissions":{"read":{"access":"open"},"update":{"access":"owner"},"delete":{"access":"owner"}}}

- Added a record from my app with 'ööää' successfully, but Admin view is forever corrupted from now on.

Image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/106346333@N02/10435376175/

Note: Bottom Label states: Showing 1 of 3

Return JSON:

{"CLOSED_BY_USER":false,"FRIENDLY_NAME":"ööää: Code","LAST_ACTIVITY":1382510485,"PRO_TEAM":null,"SHARED_SECRET":"salaisuus","SHARING_PROFILE":2,"STARTED":1382510485,"_id":"52676fa0535c12d655000bad","_parent_id":null,"created_at":1382510496,"updated_at":1382510496,"user_id":604824,"permissions":{"read":{"access":"open"},"update":{"access":"owner"},"delete":{"access":"owner"}}}

The behavior is the same with: Opera, Chrome and IE

Please I really hope this issue to be fixed, since hiding complete content of a class makes developing / debugging really hard and only way to fix it is to delete the parent record (user). And that is totally out of the question when the App is live.

Best,
Janne

Comment: Seems to be Fixed in current version. Thanks